# Problems setting up SSL connections for MySQL on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, ssl, ubuntu-14.04

I've been banging my head for a few days on this and I'm really at the end of my rope...

I'm trying to set up SSL connections on MySQL 5.7.10 running on ubuntu 14.04 and no matter what I do, the user required to use SSL is always rejected with access denied when trying to connect.

I was able to set up SSL easily on Windows (our dev machines) but for the love of me cannot get it to work on Linux.

I tried to use the certificates provided when installing MySQL (located in the /var/lib/mysql directory).  I also tried to generate new ones using [this procedure](https://oracle-base.com/articles/mysql/mysql-configure-ssl-connections).  I even tried to import the certificates that I generated using MySQL Workbench on Windows (the ones that actually worked on windows) but nothing works.

When starting up MySQL, SSL seems to be okay, as I only get this in /var/log/mysql/err.log

```
2015-12-17T18:25:32.687582Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate /var/lib/mysql/ca.pem is self signed.
```

SSL is ON in MySQL

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%SSL%';
+---------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                          |
+---------------+--------------------------------+
| have_openssl  | YES                            |
| have_ssl      | YES                            |
| ssl_ca        | /var/lib/mysql/ca.pem          |
| ssl_capath    |                                |
| ssl_cert      | /var/lib/mysql/server-cert.pem |
| ssl_cipher    |                                |
| ssl_crl       |                                |
| ssl_crlpath   |                                |
| ssl_key       | /var/lib/mysql/server-key.pem  |
+---------------+--------------------------------+
```

I've put the paths to the server and client certificates in the /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
[client]
# SSL Settings
ssl-ca=/var/lib/mysql/ca.pem
ssl-cert=/var/lib/mysql/client-cert.pem
ssl-key=/var/lib/mysql/client-key.pem

[mysqld]
# SSL Settings
ssl-ca=/var/lib/mysql/ca.pem
ssl-cert=/var/lib/mysql/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/var/lib/mysql/server-key.pem
```

I even tried to disabled appArmor for mysql in case that would do it, bot I alwas get the sema result when trying to connect a test user requiring ssl as such:

```
CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'test'@'localhost' REQUIRE ssl;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

When trying to connect:

```
> /usr/bin$ mysql -u test -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Same thing when manually specifying the client certificates:

```
> mysql --ssl-ca=/var/lib/mysql/ca.pem --ssl-cert=/var/lib/mysql/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=/var/lib/mysql/client-key.pem --host=localhost --user=test --password
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Does anybody have any idea?  I fail to see why a setuyp that works fine on windows would give me such grief on linux.

Is there a way to debug this further?

Thansk in advance
/Sebas

Comment: Try: `$ mysql --ssl -u test -p`, after: `mysql> SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_version';`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  I cannot connect using ssl users, therefore when I connect (using non-ssl users), the Ssl_version value is empty.

Comment: For what it's worth I'm using the MySQL community edition so it only supports yaSSL not Openssl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My test:

error.log:

```bsh
[Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
```

```bsh
$ sudo mysql
```

```sql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 11
Server version: 5.7.10 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SELECT VERSION(); -- MySQL Community Server
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.10    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%';
+---------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value           |
+---------------+-----------------+
| have_openssl  | YES             |
| have_ssl      | YES             |
| ssl_ca        | ca.pem          |
| ssl_capath    |                 |
| ssl_cert      | server-cert.pem |
| ssl_cipher    |                 |
| ssl_crl       |                 |
| ssl_crlpath   |                 |
| ssl_key       | server-key.pem  |
+---------------+-----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test' REQUIRE SSL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
```

```bsh
$ mysql -u test -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

$ mysql -u test -p --ssl
Enter password:
```

```sql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 12
Server version: 5.7.10 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

You are enforcing ssl conection via unix socket. Please consider
switching ssl off as it does not make connection via unix socket
any more secure.
mysql> SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE '%Ssl_version%';
+---------------+---------+
| Variable_name | Value   |
+---------------+---------+
| Ssl_version   | TLSv1.1 |
+---------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE:** The test details.

mysqld.cnf:

```bsh
[client]
...
# SSL Settings
ssl-ca=/var/lib/mysql/ca.pem
ssl-cert=/var/lib/mysql/client-cert.pem
ssl-key=/var/lib/mysql/client-key.pem

[mysqld]
...
# SSL Settings
ssl-ca=/var/lib/mysql/ca.pem
ssl-cert=/var/lib/mysql/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/var/lib/mysql/server-key.pem
```

Yes, certificates are auto-generated by MySQL. See [6.3.13 Creating SSL and RSA Certificates and Keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-ssl-rsa-files.html). Check the security permissions to access the certificates.

error.log:

```bsh
[Warning] CA certificate /var/lib/mysql/ca.pem is self signed.
```

```bsh
$ sudo mysql
```

```sql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 11
Server version: 5.7.10 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SELECT VERSION(); -- MySQL Community Server
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.10    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%';
+---------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                          |
+---------------+--------------------------------+
| have_openssl  | YES                            |
| have_ssl      | YES                            |
| ssl_ca        | /var/lib/mysql/ca.pem          |
| ssl_capath    |                                |
| ssl_cert      | /var/lib/mysql/server-cert.pem |
| ssl_cipher    |                                |
| ssl_crl       |                                |
| ssl_crlpath   |                                |
| ssl_key       | /var/lib/mysql/server-key.pem  |
+---------------+--------------------------------+
9 rows in set (0,01 sec)

mysql> CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test' REQUIRE SSL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
```

```bsh
$ mysql -u test -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

$ mysql -u test -p --ssl
Enter password:
```

```sql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 12
Server version: 5.7.10 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

You are enforcing ssl conection via unix socket. Please consider
switching ssl off as it does not make connection via unix socket
any more secure.
mysql> SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE '%Ssl_version%';
+---------------+---------+
| Variable_name | Value   |
+---------------+---------+
| Ssl_version   | TLSv1.1 |
+---------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I've tried to setup same everything but my mysql is not restarting after changing the my.cnf with above client and server changes

Comment: @AlwaysSunny What error do you get in the MySQL logs? Do you have the correct permissions to access the certificates?

Comment: now restarting works but when I try `mysql -u root -p` it returns `ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed`, then I try to use the --ssl params but those are not showing any error but only some messages. see: https://pasteboard.co/cyUhQWlQdVMf.png

Comment: @AlwaysSunny Check the path of the certificates.

Comment: yes sir, the same file paths works fine while I am testing with MySQL workbench(without SSL not connecting and with SSL certificates it works). but not sure why not with the MySQL command line though. I just moved those to desktop, `mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 –-ssl-ca=/home/kamal/Desktop/mysql-certs/ca.pem –-ssl-cert=/home/kamal/Desktop/mysql-certs/client-cert.pem –-ssl-key=/home/kamal/Desktop/mysql-certs/client-key.pem` thanks for the reply.

Comment: @AlwaysSunny It looks like a permission problem on the previous directory.

Comment: hello sir can you please have a look on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73511622/connecting-mysql-local-database-from-remote-server-with-ssl

Comment: @AlwaysSunny Were you able to solve the problem? I see you deleted the question from the [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342300/problems-setting-up-ssl-connections-for-mysql-on-ubuntu-14-04/34358259#comment129815428_34358259).

Comment: no sir IP address doesn't work for me but local tunnelling with ngrok works(but without even needing SSL)